# How to download the image if we have given url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-imaging-library

I have the following URLs, I want to download these images using a code. There is millions of URL so I want to do it using python.

```
1) https://image.lexica.art/md/dbbb96f1-fce2-4970-ab62-b4b4e6859fe9
2) https://image.lexica.art/md/76318f25-5736-4cda-965d-96fe34823263
3) https://image.lexica.art/md/c11dd279-757e-43ff-8305-43e106f6c345
4) https://image.lexica.art/md/f38d92bb-99bc-4611-938f-c5d6cc70d6ea
```

**I have tried the following code but didn't work.**

```
url = 'https://image.lexica.art/md/76318f25-5736-4cda-965d-96fe34823263'
folder_path = 'images_artistics'
file_name = url.split('/')[-1][:-4]

image_content = requests.get(url).content
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
f = open(file_path, 'wb')
image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
print(f"SAVED - {url} - AT: {file_path}")
```

Error that I am getting;
[image]

Comment: Please do not post (incomplete) pictures of error messages - post actual messages. Please ensure your code is complete - that includes the necessary `import` statements. Please look at the data you receive from a `request` to make sure it at least starts with the correct magic signature of an image. If you are downloading millions of images, each with a delay, you will be there for ages so you need to consider multiprocessing or async solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather complicated ... from wireshark trace, i see it's using HTTP2 and i'm guessing server also checks for browser-like HTTP headers (eg. "User-Agent", etc)

make sure you install httpx with http2 `pip3 install 'httpx[http2]'`

then try this,

```
import httpx
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import httpx
import asyncio

async def main():
    url_list = [
        'https://image.lexica.art/md/dbbb96f1-fce2-4970-ab62-b4b4e6859fe9',
        #'https://image.lexica.art/md/76318f25-5736-4cda-965d-96fe34823263',
        #'https://image.lexica.art/md/c11dd279-757e-43ff-8305-43e106f6c345',
        #'https://image.lexica.art/md/f38d92bb-99bc-4611-938f-c5d6cc70d6ea',
    ]

    headers = {
        'Host': 'image.lexica.art',
        'authority': 'image.lexica.art',
        'method': 'GET',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image,webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'macOS',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    for url in url_list:
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True)
        response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).convert('RGB')
        image.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run( main() )
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I would use `requests` for this.

```
import requests

url_list = [
    'https://image.lexica.art/md/dbbb96f1-fce2-4970-ab62-b4b4e6859fe9',
    'https://image.lexica.art/md/76318f25-5736-4cda-965d-96fe34823263',
    'https://image.lexica.art/md/c11dd279-757e-43ff-8305-43e106f6c345',
    'https://image.lexica.art/md/f38d92bb-99bc-4611-938f-c5d6cc70d6ea',
]

for url in url_list:
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(url)
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.content)
```

Comment: can you see, what is the response? I am getting 403.

Comment: do you have downloaded the image using the request? try your code, and download the image. I don't think so, it will work

Comment: The code works, I think the page is denying access because of missing header information. I found out that those are webp images, so you might still have to conver them if the donwload works. I'll try to figure it out later, maybe I'll find something

Comment: Exactly, I will be waiting for your response.

Comment: I can't find a way to do this. Cloudeflare is protecting this page and they are investing a lot of money to do so. Others tried the same thing and failed. I'm not even sure if it is legal to collect those images this way. I'm sorry, but I can't help you.